# kdevelop linking trouble

Tags: linker, cmake, kdevelop

After adding a new class to a KDevelop C++ project, linker has a problem to find exact sources (calculation.cpp in this case):

```
-- Build files have been written to: /var/www/C++/fibonacci/build
Scanning dependencies of target fibonacci
Linking CXX executable fibonacci
CMakeFiles/fibonacci.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/var/www/C++/fibonacci/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Calculation::fibonacci(unsigned int)'
/var/www/C++/fibonacci/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `Calculation::fibonacci_req(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [fibonacci] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fibonacci.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Failed ***
```

There is no option in kdevelop interface to set files that should be linked or not. How to solve the linking problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the source files to your project in the CMakeLists.txt file. Replace:

```
add_executable(example main.cpp)
```

with:

```
set(MySources main.cpp calculation.h calculation.cpp)

add_executable(example ${MySources})
```

and this should be it.